# Form field not showing in tempate

Tags: html, django, django-forms

after defining form field when I try to access in django template using {{form.Date_Joined}}

not working

```
class UserAdd(forms.ModelForm):
        
    class Meta:
        model=CompanyUsers
        fields= '__all__'
        exclude=['usrPsswd','usrId','usrCmpnyId','lstLogin','is_active','usrDOJ']
        widgets={

                
                'Date_Joined':forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
            }
```

The widget i've declare not showing

````
    <div class="order">
        <!-- <div class="head" > -->
             <h4> ADD COMPANY</h4>
        <!-- </div> -->
         <table id="table-datas">
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <tbody>
           <tr><td>Username</td><br><td>{{ form.usrNme}}</td></tr>
           <tr><td>First Name </td><br><td>{{ form.usrFNme}}</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Last Name </td><br><td>{{ form.usrLNme}}</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Date of join</td><br><td>{{form.Date_Joined}}</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Department</td><br><td>{{ form.usrDpt}}</td></tr>
           <tr><td>Email</td><br><td>{{ form.usrMail}}</td></tr>
                    
           <tr><td><button type="submit">Register</button></td></tr>
           </form>```


so the Date Joined field shows nothing
````

Comment: you can not set the `type` as `attrs`, since that is determined elsewhere.

Comment: Can you share the `CompanyUsers` model...

Answer (score 1):

The `type` of the `attrs` is not taken into account, this originates from the `input_type` of the widget, you thus create a custom widget:

```
class MyDateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
```

then we plug this in as widget:

```
class UserAdd(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CompanyUsers
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = [
            'usrPsswd',
            'usrId',
            'usrCmpnyId',
            'lstLogin',
            'is_active',
            'usrDOJ',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'Date_Joined': MyDateInput,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you make a mistake with the typo field of the form **`Date_Joined`** because python is case sensitive.

Type

```py
widgets={
  'date_Joined':forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
}
```

Instead of

```py
widgets={
  'Date_Joined':forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
}
```